# 2d array in C. Fixed width but unknown height?

Tags: c, arrays, 2d

Is it possible to make an array with an unknown height but a set width?

So that It can be something like:

```
|----------8-----------|

[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]  |
[1][1][1][1][1][1][1][1]  |
[2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2]  |
[3][3][3][3][3][3][3][3] \|/
```

So that it can be as big as it needs but stays 8 floats wide.

I have a feeling that the declaration will look somewhat like:

```
    float *array[8] // maybe???
```

or

```
    float array[8][] // idk???
```

Im not used to multiple pointers on a var (I get confused still). I use apple's cocoa framework a lot so I would normally use NSArray but the thing I'm building requires a C-based array not a class.

Comment: What do you mean by height and width?  array[width][height] or array[height][width]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
float (*array)[8];
```

...which declares `array` as a pointer to 8-element arrays of float.

You can then allocate space for the whole thing as follows:

```
array = malloc(sizeof(*array) * num_elements);
```

Then, `array[3][0]`, for example, would access the first float in the 4th array of 8 floats.

Comment: Thank you. I would have never guessed to use parentheses. As I said to Brian, I wish I could pick 2 answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
float *array[8];
```

Now you have an array of 8 `float` pointers.

For each one of these, you would then need to allocate space when you know how large it needs to be:

```
array[0] = calloc(numMembers, sizeof(float));
```

If you later decided you needed a specific second dimension to be larger, you would need to reallocate.

Comment: Because my brain often doesn't communicate well with my fingers :) Thx - fixed.

Comment: @BrianRoach Dude I see you on this site all the time. I want to thank you for all the help that you have provided me and other members of this community. I wish I could pick 2 answers. Again, thank you.

Comment: Thank you :) I learn a lot by helping other people. Also helps me keep some skills from going completely rusty that I don't use daily at work (Like my C ).

Answer (score 0):

Yes It definatly is:

```
  float *p2DArray[8];

  for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    p2DArray[i] = (float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*WIDTH);
  }
```

taken from [Multi-Dimensional Arrays](http://pleasemakeanote.blogspot.com/2008/06/2d-arrays-in-c-using-malloc.html)

Comment: very true :P I changed it as soon as I saw the C++ code lol, too much C++ is bad for C programming.

Comment: @Serdalis I know how you feel. I spent 6 months doing assembly and when I cam back to C, I felt like a pointer was way too complex. XD

Answer (score 0):

As an argument to a function, you can require a 2d array of unknown height, as so

```
void foo(int arr[][8])
{
     //...do stuff with arr...
}
```